# Scrollbar inside link problem with FireFox only

Tags: html, css, firefox

So, the problem is this:
With Firefox if you **try to click and drag a scrollbar** that is inside a link it will just try to move the link area.. normal clicking and mouse scrolling works but clicking and dragging does not.

This demonstrates the problem (**in firefox only**)
http://jsfiddle.net/jz6jW/

Any ideas on how to get past this?

**Edit:
for my own situation this solves the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/jz6jW/7/
( to add links to both the text and img instead of just putting everything inside the links )**

Comment: try to use the latest firefox.

Comment: @klox it happends in all the versions of firefox as far as my testing shows.. ( couple latest ones anyways )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an odd bug. I'd guess that Firefox is considering the span's scrollbar to be part of the span. Since the span-with-scrollbar is inside the `<a>`, the click on the scrollbar is interpreted as a click on the `<a>`, you should notice the usual anchor coloring change as soon as you click on the scrollbar's thumb.

However, it works okay in Firefox if you put the `<a>` inside the `<span>`:

```
<span class="container">
    <a href="#">
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
    </a>
</span>
```

And:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6rg4m/

**UPDATE**: Based on http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wPyms/, your CSS is a bit odd:

```
.Text {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This one is floated to the left and absolutely positioned (without specifying the position at that) and that doesn't make much sense to me. Also, it looks like you are trying to position the image as a background for the text so why not just size the container to match the image and make the image the container's background? This lets you simplify your markup and your CSS and won't confuse Firefox (I doubt it would confuse any browser).

I think the following will give you the appearance and behavior you're after. The image in your jsfiddle doesn't go anywhere so I changed it to a kitten.

HTML:

```
<div class="Cont">
    <a href="#">
        <!-- ... -->
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Cont {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #888;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: url(http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2654/3822981633_abc0213105.jpg);
}

.Cont a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EgUwH/2/

This is pretty much the same as my original suggestion.

Comment: @muiistooshort For what i need it for i cant use that :/ Otherwise that does make sense. You said "I'd guess that Firefox is considering the span's scrollbar to be part of the span." this is where it gets weird... even if i make the <a> tag the element that adds scroll it is still the same.. http://jsfiddle.net/jz6jW/4/

Comment: That's an interesting fiddle, unfortunately. Clicking on the scrollbar thumb in WebKit activates the `a:active` styling but the scrollbar still works. Opera behaves as WebKit does. Hmmm. Do you absolutely need an `<a>` or could you use a `<div>` with a click handler? You could include a normal `<a>` inside the `<div>` to keep it accessible.

Comment: @muiistooshort unfortunately it has to be... i have one possible solution but its super complicated and id rather keep it as it is.. ( though the code would be valid no matter what... )

Comment: So this DOM structure is an external requirement? Any chance of posting a larger example with more context?

Comment: @muiistooshort This is more or less the whole structure. http://jsfiddle.net/jz6jW/5/ it might not be totally accurate as i wrote it by hand as i dont have the original at my reach at the moment.

Comment: @Lollero: Check my update. I think you might have started building a solution and then got lost down the garden path trying to make it work when you should have started fresh.

Comment: @muiistooshort using background image is a good one. I wouldve used that if in this case i wouldnt have to use <img>. Otherwise that is a good solution.

Comment: @muiistooshort Despite the fact that my code is what it is.. i figured out a solution. Problem with the solution given a few times ( putting link inside the span ) was simply that it was not enough. If i do so, i will have link just around the text and i need it around the image as well.. at first i though..what about wrapping image inside a link? well.. of course then the text blocks that link but if i wrap both text and image inside link it solves the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/jz6jW/7/

Answer (score 1):

< a >  tag is an in line element 
you cannot put tags in it sorry

here try this link
http://jsfiddle.net/jz6jW/1/

Comment: With HTML5, you can put `<a>`'s around block level elements, which means that in theory Firefox should handle that link correctly.

Comment: you can make <a> tag an block element just written display:block; inside <a> tag

Comment: yes you do that but have to add another class or id to it here in this case

Answer (score 0):

This is a [very old Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324024) since 2006. Surprisingly it's not fixed till today. And I was the lucky one to meet it.

After some experiments, I found the fix quite simple as well, remove the `href` attribute on the `<a>` element.

This works fine in Firefox:

```
<a>
    <span class="container">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
    </span>
</a>
```